# Excel Custom Function go infinite loop by itself, "End Function" works like "Next" or "Loop"

Tags: excel, vba, function, infinite-loop, udf

I have two versions of an Excel Workbook. They are basically in same structure. For some reason, I need to copy some cells from Version A to Version B, so I wrote a custom function called GetVal(), the code are:

```
Function GetVal(cur As Range)
Dim CurSheet As String, RowN As Integer, ColN As Integer
RowN = cur.Row
ColN = cur.Column
CurSheet = cur.Parent.Name
GetVal = Workbooks("BIG Inventory Data - 2015  P10W1.xlsx").Worksheets(CurSheet).Cells(RowN, ColN).Value
End Function
```

Then I just typed "=GetVal(A1)" in Cell A1, the data of A1 from anther workbook will show up automatically. This Custom function worked very well at the beginning.

After I used this function to fill in all the data I need, I wrote anther Sub trying to converting all the getval() formula into pure value. Here is the simplified  test code:

```
'First I Set the test Range to this GetVal function
Sheets("vba").Range("A1").Formula = "=GetVal(Partner_HLJ!D3)"
'Then I convert it into pure value
Sheets("vba").Range("A1") = Sheets("vba").Range("A1").Value
```

But it stuck in the first step. It goes into infinite loop. When I used F8 to go step by step, I found it's always looping in the GetVal() Function, the "End Function" works like "Next" in a For loop.....I feel very confused...

By the way, the Original Converting Sub code is like

```
Sub Convert_GetVal_Formula_To_Value_Only()
Dim i As Integer, cl As Range
For Each cl Range("A1:E3715")
If cl.Formula Like "=GetVal*" Then
cl = cl.value
End If
Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` just prior to  conversion to pure value ?

Comment: Is it really looping, or the user-defined-function (UDF) is again called from another cell? It seems you are calling the UDF from a large number of cells s (`Range("A1:E3715")`) that is 18757 cells). The UDF is called that many times, so you'd think it is looping around.

Comment: @A.S.H It's already looping in the simplified test code

Comment: In your OP you said that when applied on a single cell (A1) there is no problem. What is the *simplified test code*?

Comment: @A.S.H It's just the code I used to test the UDF.

Comment: This thread is old, but I will put this here anyway (another thing to look out for): I have recently experienced the same problem, and figured out that I forgot to put an equals sign when returning the value for the function... so it kept calling itself.